# Stanford NLP Tagger via NLTK - tag_sents splits everything into chars

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm hoping someone has experience with this as I'm unable to find any comments online besides a bug report from 2015 regarding the NERtagger which is probably the same.

Anyway, I'm trying to batch process text to get around the poor performing base tagger.  From what I understand, tag_sents should help.

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
from nltk import word_tokenize
import nltk

stanford_model = 'stanford-postagger/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger'
stanford_jar = 'stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar'
tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(stanford_model, stanford_jar)
tagger.java_options = '-mx4096m'
text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
print tagger.tag_sents(text)
```

Except no matter what I pass to the tag_sents method, the text gets split up into chars instead of words.  Anyone know why it doesn't work properly?  This works as expected...

```
tag(text)
```

I tried splitting the sentence into tokens as well to see if that helped but same treatment

Comment: This is likely because `tag_sents()` expects a list of sentences, but `word_tokenize()` is producing a list of words.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter what I pass it.  I tried both just the string and tokenized words just in case.  I'll update...thanks!

Comment: What if you pass it as a list? Like `tagger.tag_sents([text])` ?
I'm having trouble running StanfordPOSTagger, so I'm unable to run these myself.

Comment: No worries.  I appreciate the help.  Still in chars.  I think we're just going to go with NLTK's pos tagger for now

[[(u'T', u'NN'), (u'h', u'NN'), (u'e', u'SYM'), (u'q', u'FW'), (u'u', u'FW'), (u'i', u'FW'), (u'c', u'NN'), (u'k', u'NN'), (u'b', u'NN'), (u'r', u'NN')...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tag_sents` function takes a list of list of strings.

```
tagger.tag_sents(word_tokenize("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."))
```

Here's a useful idiom:

```
 tagger.tag_sents(word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(text))
```

where `text` is a string.

Comment: It will be more useful if you drop the list brackets and turn it into a generator expression!

Comment: Thanks @alexis! Changed.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of what alvas said, which worked for me: `tagger.tag_sents([[text]])`.